# Is there a way to list all files in all folders and sub-folders in data lake?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to list all files in all folders and sub folders.  I'm trying to get everything into a RDD or a dataframe (I don't think it matters because it's just a list of file names and paths).  I found some code online that looks promising, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  I'm pretty new to Scala though, so maybe I just missed something simple.

First code sample:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

val inputPath: String = "mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/corp/*.gz"

val df = spark.read.text(inputPath)
  .select(input_file_name, $"value")
  .as[(String, String)] // Optionally convert to Dataset
  .rdd // or RDD
```

Second code sample:

```
import java.io.File

def getListOfFiles(dir: String):List[File] = {
  val d = new File(dir)
  if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
    d.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
  } else {
    List[File]()
  }
}

val files = getListOfFiles("mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/corp/")
```

Comment: if you are using databricks try this var files=dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/airlines")

Comment: Thanks Mahesh.  Is this for a Scala environment?  I am using Scala in Databricks and this doesn't work for me.  I have never been able to use 'dbutils.fs.ls' in my environment.  This seems like a pretty basic thing, but it simply does not work for me.  I have only been using DB for the past 6 months, so I'm kind of new to it, but it seems like something pretty simple should work pretty easily.  Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything but throw errors.

Comment: yes, this is for the scala environment with data bricks. could you add those error which you faced

Answer (score 0):

There's useful `Files.walk` method for recursive tree traversal in `nio` package.

```
import java.nio.file._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val files = Files.walk(FileSystems.getDefault.getPath("mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/corp")).iterator.asScala.toList
```

Just note it returns both files and directories, so you need to filter in case you only need files.

Comment: Hello there, Kombajn.  I just ran your code sample and I got this error:
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/corp*
Did I miss something?  I am running this in a Scala environment.

Comment: Both files and directories are totally fine!  I can copy/paste to Excel, and filter out what I don't need.  Creating a data-frame and saving everything to a CSV would be ideal!

Comment: does this actually work for you?  The files definitely exist in the lake.  I have several TB of data in there.  It keeps telling me there is nothing there.

Comment: I don't have this exact path, but yes, it works for me. Try providing absolute path (`/mnt/...`).

Comment: I didn't get if you actually want to list files only or load their contents into a dataframe.

Comment: I tried '/mnt/'.  It doesn't work for me; it has never worked for me.  I want to list only the file NAMES in a structured dataframe.  I don't want to load the data into a dataframe.  Is that possible?  I think so, but I can't get anything working.